# Proper use of sqlalchemy scoped_session and pyramid's models

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm having problem with finding *a proper way* of using db queries. I don't have much experience with web development, it's like 6 months of working afterhours (so it's like max 10h a week). I choose Pyramid because of Py3k support mainly. It doesn't have that much community support as django, nor the tutorials, so I might be doing things wrong. So...

I'm using Pyramid(1.4) and SQLAlchemy (0.8). I've created project just as described in Pyramid's tutorial.

I've already read this excellent post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11547942/1498245) about using `scoped_session`.

But.. I've been struggling with proper (if such exist) approach to DB objects handling.

So here's what I begun with:

```
## Project layout
myproject
├── models
│   ├── somemodel1.py
│   ├── somemodel2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── meta.py
│   └── somemodel3.py
├── schemas
│   ├── some_colander_schema1.py
│   ├── some_colander_schema2.py
│   └── some_colander_schema3.py
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── initializedb.py
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── jquery-1.9.1.min.js
│   └── transparent.gif
├── templates
│   ├── some_chameleon_template.pt
│   ├── some_chameleon_template1.pt
│   ├── some_chameleon_template2.pt
│   ├── forbidden_view.pt
│   ├── global_layout_noauth.pt
│   └── global_layout.pt
├── views
│   ├── someviewclass1.py
│   ├── someviewclass2.py
│   └── someviewclass3.py
└── __init__.py


# models/meta.py PRE @contextmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

DBSession   = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base        = declarative_base()
```

Now to the point.

In my views I was using this construct:

```
class SomeView1(Layout): #in Layout class request is saved to self.request
    @view_config(...)
    def list(self):
        DBSession()
        try:
            somethings = DBSession.query(SomeModel).options(eagerload(...)).filter(...).all()
        except: #it's bad to catch everything I know, but had to close session properly
            somethings = []
            DBSession.rollback()
        DBSession.remove()

        ... #do something more

        DBSession()
        try:
            somethingMores = DBSession.query(SomeModel2).options(eagerload(...)).filter(...).all()
        except: #it's bad to catch everything I know, but had to close session properly
            somethingMores = []
            DBSession.rollback()
        DBSession.remove()

        return {"values" : somethings,
                "others" : somethingMores}

    @view_config(...)
    def edit(self):
        # here's recently implemented "update"
        DBSession()
        try:
            somethings = DBSession.query(SomeModel1)...all()
            somethingsMore = DBSession.query(SomeModel2)...all()
        finally:
            DBSession.remove()
        return {"somethings":somethings,
                "somethingsMore": somethingsMore}
```

But then I realized I've got bunches of such queries.. so I moved them into Model.

In my view I just had to call:

```
somethings = SomeModel1.all()
#or
something = SomeModel.by_id(some_id)
```

and in that `SomeModel1` I had for example:

```
class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "somemodel"
    idsomeModel = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        DBSession()
        try:
            retval = ...
        except:
            retval = None
        finally:
            DBSession.remove()
        return retval
```

It's all great (not really, but wait..) but it get's nasty when I have to for example put sort order or **where** clause. Then my `def all(cls)` turned into `def all(cls, **kwargs)` and lots of `if`s, like:

```
query = DBSession.query(SomeModel)
if "forPeriod" in kwargs:
    query = query.filter(SomeModel.date > kwargs["forPeriod"])
if "sortOrder" in kwargs:
    query = query.order_by(kwargs["sort"])

retval = query.all()
```

Is it ok? or should I write queries in my views? I guess there's no "good way", but I feel like this approach is more maintainable.

And it's not good. Now I've read on sqlalchemy site, that it's far more better to pass session to model. In this way in my view I'd use it like:

```
@view_config(...)
def some_function(self):
    with get_db_session as session:
        somethings = SomeModel.all(session, some_arguments)
```

that function `get_db_session` is from new `models/meta.py`:

```
# models/meta.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager

DBSession   = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base        = declarative_base()

@contextmanager
def get_scoped_session():
    try:
        yield DBSession()
    finally:
        DBSession.remove()
```

It's a hell of a post, but I want someone to tell me "Ok, you're going in good direction" or "No, f*ck man, what are you doing?"

So to sum everything up:

1. Is hiding queries in models a good idea? (sometimes with lots of `if`s on `kwargs`; and obscuring exceptions - if such happens my return value is None, cause in view I don't care what was the reason, I got it logged (in model))
2. Is such use of scoped_session with `@contextmanager` and `with` statement a good approach?
3. No, there's no 3rd question.. so much text just to ask two questions :/

Answer (score 2):

for #1:

I would use the scoped_session.query_property() for queries, and not hide them that much, setup your Base as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

DBSession = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        extension='ZopeTransactionExtension'  # for your 2nd question
    )
)

class ORMClass(object):
    query = DBSession.query_property()

Base = declarative_base(cls=ORMClass)
```

and derive your models from this Base class as usual:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    ...
```

now you will be able to:

```
MyModel.query.filter_by(attr1='something').all()
```

for #2:
I agree with umeboshi, use a transaction manager

Comment: I'm gonna try it out, and give you a reply what do I think about it.

I cannot see where the DBSession handling is placed in here, as it is hidden in Base class. What happens when something goes wrong? Hand made rollback and session removal?

Answer (score 1):

As far as #2 is concerned, I use [transaction](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transaction)

```
with transaction.manager:
    p = Page()
    p.title = "Page Title"
    p.content = "Page Content"
    dbsession.add(p)
p = dbsession.merge(p)
```

Comment: So #2 looks like a good approach? In your example how is session managed? What happens when there's an exception on dbsession?

Comment: When an exception occurs during the transaction, the `__exit__` method of the context manager aborts the transaction, optionally retry the transaction if the exception raised is a transient exception, or if unable to retry, it will reraise the exception, yet leave you without an uncommitted transaction.