# Sqlalchemy: Using decorator to provide thread-safe session for multiple functions

Tags: python, multithreading, session, sqlalchemy, decorator

I am working on something similar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544774/) (multithreaded app with sqlalchemy), so I understood, that I should create a new session for each db-query.

I wonder, if using a decorator for each method, which needs DB-access would make sense, or if there are traps using this approach. The decorator is constructed following [the last example here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it).

```
def dbconnect(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        session = Session()  # with all the requirements
        try:
            func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
    return inner

@dbconnect
def some_function(some, arguments, session)
    session.query(...) # no commit, close, rollback required

some_function("many", "different_arguments") 
#session is not required, since provided by decorator
```

This would make it comparable easy to provide thread-safe DB-access to any function, without the need of implementing the whole try-except-finally-stuff redundant, but I am not sure, if this approach is fail-safe and pythonic, or if there exists another best-practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators that add arguments are interesting but potentially tricky. The argument list as defined is now out of step with what callers will actually use. If you explicitly pass `session=something` to this it will raise an exception (though you could check for that in the decorator)

You'll also want to add at least a `functools.wraps` (granted, this is short sample code).

Transactions are a good use case for context managers. See [What's the recommended scoped_session usage pattern in a multithreaded sqlalchemy webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544774/whats-the-recommended-scoped-session-usage-pattern-in-a-multithreaded-sqlalchem) for an idea on that.

Answer (score 7):

I think it here would make sense to use a [`scoped_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions), maybe like this:

```
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def dbconnect(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        session = Session()  # (this is now a scoped session)
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs) # No need to pass session explicitly
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            Session.remove()  # NOTE: *remove* rather than *close* here
    return inner

@dbconnect
def some_function(some, arguments):
    session = Session()
    # 'session' is  now a handle to the *same* session as in the decorator
    session.query(...) # no commit, close, rollback required

some_function("many", "different_arguments") 
#session is not required, since provided by decorator
```

(Warning: Untested)

Comment: I am fairly sure this raise will prevent session.remove() from executing.

Comment: Do you mean the `raise` inside the `except` block?  I don't think so, at least not reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).  I'm happy to be proven wrong with a mini example though!

Comment: The remove is in a finally block which 'guarantees' that it will be called.